# python: arbitrary precision

Tags: python

I try to make this simple program to compute the derivative of a function with normal precision:

```
# second derivative of a function
def diff2(f, x, h=1E-6):
        r = (f(x-h) - 2*f(x) + f(x+h))/float(h*h)
        return r

# define the function to derivate
def g(t):
        return t**(-6)

# decresing h increasing the precision of the derivative
# ROUND-OFF problems are present
for k in range(1,15):
        h = 10**(-k) # 15 different value of h
        d2g = diff2(g, 1, h) # compute d'' of g 15-th times in point t=1
        print 'h=%.0e: %.5f' % (h, d2g)
```

As one can see from the printing operation I have problem when k is larger than 8 due to round off. I know I can use:

`from decimal import *`

But I do not know how to implement these command in my functions.

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the decimal module:

```
from decimal import Decimal

# second derivative of a function
def diff2(f, x, h=1E-6):
    x, h = Decimal(x), Decimal(h)
    r = (f(x - h) - 2 * f(x) + f(x + h)) / Decimal(h * h)
    return r
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the derivative at position x_0 and perform your calculation with floats the optimal value for `h` which minimizes the numerical error is `sqrt(sys.float_info.epsilon)*x_0` which is approximately 1E-8 for your case where `x_0=1`.

For further information and a derivation of this value see the chapter `How to Choose h`starting at page 4 until the end in [this short script on Numerical Differentiation](http://www.karenkopecky.net/Teaching/eco613614/Notes_NumericalDifferentiation.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It is worth looking into the python module [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/), which can handle arbitrary precision. For example:

```
>>> from mpmath import mp
>>> mp.dps = 50
>>> print(mp.quad(lambda x: mp.exp(-x**2), [-mp.inf, mp.inf]) ** 2)
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
```

You could simply change types and let your functions work with greater precision. It is worth noting the comments and the answer by @halex however.